# Unrecognized token: "@" in Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-views

I am trying to make a search through multiple fields in one model but I get this error all the time:
unrecognized token: "@"

However I think it is a database issue I couldn't find a solution for it. I am posting my views.py and the traceback and would be very happy if someone could take a look.

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector


class SearchView(ListView):
    model=User
    template_name='search.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = User.objects.annotate(search=SearchVector('username','last_name'),).filter(search=query)
        return object_list
```

**Traceback**

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/?q=ekrem

Django Version: 3.0.8
Python Version: 3.8.1
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'crispy_forms',
 'account',
 'dictionary',
 'search']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\ekrem\Documents\Django\project\beehive\templates\base.html, error at line 5
   unrecognized token: "@"
   1 : <!DOCTYPE html>
   2 : {%load static%}
   3 : <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
   4 :  <head>
   5 :      <link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://s tackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
   6 :      <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/elegant.css" %}">
   7 :      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   8 :      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   9 :      <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
   10 :         <meta charset="utf-8">
   11 :         <title></title>
   12 :     </head>
   13 :     <body>
   14 :         <nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-md bg-light justify-content-md-center justify-content-start fixed-top">
   15 :             <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

The above exception (unrecognized token: "@") was the direct cause of the following exception:
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 166, in render
    len_values = len(values)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 258, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1261, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1152, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 90, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Users\ekrem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 396, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /search/
Exception Value: unrecognized token: "@"
```

I was not sure which part to post of the traceback or if it is needed so I posted all of it.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The `SearchVector` is a special feature to utilize the PostgeSQL full text search. You are using SQLite as the database which does not support that.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be an unintended character in line 5 of your HTML that is being interpreted as an '@' symbol. Without the html file itself, it's hard to determine if the traceback is representing this character accurately, however.

```
<link rel ="stylesheet" href="https://s tackpath[...]
                                       ^
```